# How do I call some blocking method with a timeout in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

Is there a standard nice way to call a blocking method with a timeout in Java?  I want to be able to do:

```
// call something.blockingMethod();
// if it hasn't come back within 2 seconds, forget it
```

if that makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: As a reference, check out Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz pp. 126 - 134, specifically section 6.3.7 "Placing time limits on tasks"

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You could use an Executor:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Callable<Object> task = new Callable<Object>() {
   public Object call() {
      return something.blockingMethod();
   }
};
Future<Object> future = executor.submit(task);
try {
   Object result = future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
   // handle the timeout
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // handle the interrupts
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
   // handle other exceptions
} finally {
   future.cancel(true); // may or may not desire this
}
```

If the `future.get` doesn't return in 5 seconds, it throws a `TimeoutException`. The timeout can be configured in seconds, minutes, milliseconds or any unit available as a constant in `TimeUnit`.

See the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) for more detail.

Comment: The blocking method will continue to run even after the timeout, right?

Comment: That depends on future.cancel. Depending on what the blocking method is doing at the time, it may or may not terminate.

Comment: how can I pass parameter to the blockingMethod() ? Thanks!

Comment: @RobertAHenru: Create a new class called `BlockingMethodCallable` whose contructor accepts the parameters you want to pass to `blockingMethod()` and store them as member variables (probably as final). Then inside `call()` pass those parameters to the `blockMethod()`.

Comment: I require this in a web application for calling another external service. As a modification. I did the following so that only 1 thread gets created in the pool and following the shutdown it exits gracefully.


1. ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
2. In the finally block. I added executor.shutdownNow();

Comment: I used this approach and it is a good solution for the problem that I am solving. Only issues is that there is a thread leak some where and I am not able to fix it. 

Please help me with this regard. 

I am using this in a web application.

Comment: finally should do `future.cancel(true)` - The method cancel(boolean) in the type Future<Object> is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: From what I understand this handles exception in partent thread and does not allow for child thread to clean after itself. Is there a way to for example pass onExit colback or raise exception in method of child thread?

Comment: I used this approach to call external endpoints in my web app. highly commended.  use shutdown int he finally.

Comment: Can this be used to timeout a readLine() from a BufferedReader? I use one to read the outputstream of a Process. I'd like to timeout a readLine if it was used when the process didn't output anything to prevent the app from being blocked forever.

Comment: @ThorstenSchmitz I had the same question. Based on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/804951/1868371) and this [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stop-execution-after-certain-time#is-there-a-guarantee), I concluded that the `BufferedReader.readLine()` is not interruptible so the thread will hang until the IO operation unblocks (or times out, if supported). Nonetheless, there are alternatives by checking on `BufferedReader.ready()` before performing `readLine()`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61174641/1868371) is an example.

Answer (score 9):

You could wrap the call in a `FutureTask` and use the timeout version of get().

See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html

Comment: FutureTask isn't itself asynchronous, is it? On its own it just does things synchronously, you need to combine it with an Executor to egt asynch behaviour.

Answer (score 9):

See also Guava's [TimeLimiter](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/TimeLimiter.html) which uses an Executor behind the scenes.

Comment: Good idea. But the link is stale. Googlecode is no more.. try this link to the [SimpleTimeLimiter](https://guava.dev/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiter.html)

Answer (score 8):

It's really great that people try to implement this in so many ways. But the truth is, there is NO way.

Most developers would try to put the blocking call in a different thread and have a future or some timer. BUT there is no way in Java to stop a thread externally, let alone a few very specific cases like the Thread.sleep() and Lock.lockInterruptibly() methods that explicitly handle thread interruption.

So really you have only 3 generic options:

1. Put your blocking call on a new thread and if the time expires you just move on, leaving that thread hanging. In that case you should make sure the thread is set to be a Daemon thread. This way the thread will not stop your application from terminating.
2. Use non blocking Java APIs. So for network for example, use NIO2 and use the non blocking methods. For  reading from the console use Scanner.hasNext() before blocking etc.
3. If your blocking call is not an IO, but your logic, then you can repeatedly check for `Thread.isInterrupted()` to check if it was interrupted externally, and have another thread call `thread.interrupt()` on the blocking thread

This course about concurrency https://www.udemy.com/java-multithreading-concurrency-performance-optimization/?couponCode=CONCURRENCY

really walks through those fundamentals if you really want to understand how it works in Java. It actually talks about those specific limitations and scenarios, and how to go about them in one of the lectures.

I personally try to program without using blocking calls as much as possible. There are toolkits like Vert.x for example that make it really easy and performant to do IO and no IO operations asynchronously and in a non blocking way.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

There is also an AspectJ solution for that with [jcabi-aspects](https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-aspects) library.

```
@Timeable(limit = 30, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
public Soup cookSoup() {
  // Cook soup, but for no more than 30 minutes (throw and exception if it takes any longer
}
```

It can't get more succinct, but you have to depend on AspectJ and introduce it in your build lifecycle, of course.

There is an article explaining it further: [Limit Java Method Execution Time](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/20/limit-method-execution-time.html)

Answer (score 3):

I'm giving you here the complete code. In place of the method I'm calling, you can use your method:

```
public class NewTimeout {
    public String simpleMethod() {
        return "simple method";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        Callable<Object> task = new Callable<Object>() {
            public Object call() throws InterruptedException {
                Thread.sleep(1100);
                return new NewTimeout().simpleMethod();
            }
        };
        Future<Object> future = executor.submit(task);
        try {
            Object result = future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            System.out.println("Timeout............Timeout...........");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // handle the interrupts
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // handle other exceptions
        } finally {
            executor.shutdown(); // may or may not desire this
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        something.blockingMethod();
    }
});
thread.start();
thread.join(2000);
if (thread.isAlive()) {
    thread.stop();
}
```

Note, that stop is deprecated, better alternative is to set some volatile boolean flag, inside blockingMethod() check it and exit, like this:

```
import org.junit.*;
import java.util.*;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class ThreadTest extends TestCase {
    static class Something implements Runnable {
        private volatile boolean stopRequested;
        private final int steps;
        private final long waitPerStep;

        public Something(int steps, long waitPerStep) {
            this.steps = steps;
            this.waitPerStep = waitPerStep;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            blockingMethod();
        }

        public void blockingMethod() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < steps && !stopRequested; i++) {
                    doALittleBit();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        public void doALittleBit() throws InterruptedException {
            Thread.sleep(waitPerStep);
        }

        public void setStopRequested(boolean stopRequested) {
            this.stopRequested = stopRequested;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        final Something somethingRunnable = new Something(5, 1000);
        Thread thread = new Thread(somethingRunnable);
        thread.start();
        thread.join(2000);
        if (thread.isAlive()) {
            somethingRunnable.setStopRequested(true);
            thread.join(2000);
            assertFalse(thread.isAlive());
        } else {
            fail("Exptected to be alive (5 * 1000 > 2000)");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a [circuit breaker](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html) implementation like the one present in the [failsafe](https://github.com/jhalterman/failsafe) project on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. More simple solution. Guarantees that if block didn't execute within the time limit. the process will terminate and throws an exception.

```
public class TimeoutBlock {

 private final long timeoutMilliSeconds;
    private long timeoutInteval=100;

    public TimeoutBlock(long timeoutMilliSeconds){
        this.timeoutMilliSeconds=timeoutMilliSeconds;
    }

    public void addBlock(Runnable runnable) throws Throwable{
        long collectIntervals=0;
        Thread timeoutWorker=new Thread(runnable);
        timeoutWorker.start();
        do{ 
            if(collectIntervals>=this.timeoutMilliSeconds){
                timeoutWorker.stop();
                throw new Exception("<<<<<<<<<<****>>>>>>>>>>> Timeout Block Execution Time Exceeded In "+timeoutMilliSeconds+" Milli Seconds. Thread Block Terminated.");
            }
            collectIntervals+=timeoutInteval;           
            Thread.sleep(timeoutInteval);

        }while(timeoutWorker.isAlive());
        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<####>>>>>>>>>>> Timeout Block Executed Within "+collectIntervals+" Milli Seconds.");
    }

    /**
     * @return the timeoutInteval
     */
    public long getTimeoutInteval() {
        return timeoutInteval;
    }

    /**
     * @param timeoutInteval the timeoutInteval to set
     */
    public void setTimeoutInteval(long timeoutInteval) {
        this.timeoutInteval = timeoutInteval;
    }
}
```

example :

```
try {
        TimeoutBlock timeoutBlock = new TimeoutBlock(10 * 60 * 1000);//set timeout in milliseconds
        Runnable block=new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //TO DO write block of code 
            }
        };

        timeoutBlock.addBlock(block);// execute the runnable block 

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        //catch the exception here . Which is block didn't execute within the time limit
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In special case of a blocking queue:

Generic `java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue` has a `poll` method with timeout parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Assume `blockingMethod` just sleep for some millis:

```
public void blockingMethod(Object input) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My solution is to use `wait()` and `synchronized` like this:

```
public void blockingMethod(final Object input, long millis) {
    final Object lock = new Object();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            blockingMethod(input);
            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
    }).start();
    synchronized (lock) {
        try {
            // Wait for specific millis and release the lock.
            // If blockingMethod is done during waiting time, it will wake
            // me up and give me the lock, and I will finish directly.
            // Otherwise, when the waiting time is over and the
            // blockingMethod is still
            // running, I will reacquire the lock and finish.
            lock.wait(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So u can replace

`something.blockingMethod(input)`

to

`something.blockingMethod(input, 2000)`

Hope it helps.