# Timeout a java function when a third party method call hangs

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a java application which calls a third party method, which can block indefinitely without throwing an exception.

Is it possible to wrap my method call in a timeout block (or thread, or other construct) such that I get back control after I assume the call is never returning?

Comment: See this question:
[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164301/how-do-i-call-some-blocking-method-with-a-timeout-in-java

Comment: Take a look at [this Q&A][1], in StackOverflow. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) should do what you need. Using the [awaitTermination](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method:

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown
>   request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted,
>   whichever happens first.

Answer (score 0):

all this multi threading is surely an answer but think if ur application is not a multi-threaded one, you can just store the timestamp of the moment you send the request and check it against the current timestamp. of course you will need a thread to keep track of the time. but all in all you can use that same thread for this purpose for as many functions calls you need. so dont go on implementing the runnable in ur classes. just make one tracker thread.