# java : execute a method over a maximum period of time

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, jakarta-mail

I am using the `JavaMail API` , and there is a method in the Folder class called "search" that sometimes take too long to execute. What i want is to execute this method over a maximum period of time( say for example 15 seconds in maximum) , that way i am sure that this method will not run up more than 15 seconds.

Pseudo Code

```
messages = maximumMethod(Folder.search(),15);
```

Do I have to create a thread just to execute this method and in the main thread use the wait method ?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I call some blocking method with a timeout in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164301/how-do-i-call-some-blocking-method-with-a-timeout-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is create a single threaded [executor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) which you can submit callables with. The return value is a `Future<?>` which you can get the results from. You can also say wait this long to get the results. Here is sample code:

```
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<Message[]> future = service.submit(new Callable<Message[]>() {
        @Override
        public Message[] call() throws Exception {
            return Folder.search(/*...*/);
        }
    });

    try {
        Message[] messages = future.get(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    catch(TimeoutException e) {
        // timeout
    }
```

Comment: +1, exactly what I was about to post.  Except that I would probably recommend using `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` instead of a single-threaded executor if you expected that you might be doing several of these calls in a row (e.g. in a loop).

Comment: @Daniel, I thought about doing that too. :) I just went with a single thread because it was in the same scope. But I do agree if it was going to be reused, one should use the cached executors which I think defaults to 64 threads at most.

Answer (score 1):

You could

1. mark current time
2. launch a thread that will search in the folder
3. while you get the result (still in thread) don't do anything if current time exceeds time obtained in 1 plus 15 seconds. You won't be able to stop the connection if it is pending but you could just disgard a late result.

Also, if you have access to the socket used to search the folder, you could set its timeout but I fear it's gonna be fully encapsulated by javamail.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

This SO question shows how to send a timeout exception to the client code: [How do I call some blocking method with a timeout in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164301/how-do-i-call-some-blocking-method-with-a-timeout-in-java)

You might be able to interrupt the actual search using `Thread.interrupt()`, but that depends on the method's implementation.  You may end up completing the action only to discard the results.

Comment: `interrupt()` was my first thought, but then you're relying on the thread scheduler to send  you back into the parent thread while you poll. Your parent thread would have to be `child.start(); while(true) { long now = System.cTM(); if(now - then > 15000) { child.interrupt(); break; } Thread.sleep(100); }` and you would be relying on the scheduler to each poll which is less than ideal. It would work for simple programs but if you needed something tighter it wouldn't.