# How can I read from a BufferedReader in Java without blocking?

Tags: java, stream, blocking, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I want to send a command to a server, and find out if I get a response.

Right now i am using `BufferedReader`'s `readline()` function, which blocks until there's a response from server, but all I want to do is verify that there's a response from the server in the first place.

I tried using `ready()` or `reset()` to avoid this block, but it doesn't help.

This is causing my program to get stuck waiting for the server to respond, which never happens. `InputStreamReader` seems to do the same thing, by my understanding of things.

Other questions I found here on the subject didn't answer my question,
so please if you can answer my question it will be great.

Comment: Interesting would be if the server did a `flush()` and ensure that a newline (`println`) was sent.

Comment: What's the difference between blocking until there's a response and finding out whether there's a response? You have to wait on the server in either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be all you need is the `InputStream` without wrapping it in a `BufferedReader`

```
while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
     int i = inputStream.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
     if (i < 0)
          break;
     strBuff.append(new String(tmp, 0, i));
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Changing to an InputStream is not required for this technique.

Comment: this does nothing to remove the blocking behavior

Comment: @EJP Won't it give him the ability to stop waiting if there is no input ?  In his question he said " but all I want to do is verify that there's a response from the server in the first place."

Comment: You haven't understood what I wrote. BufferedInputStream would work just the same with this code.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson you are mistaken. If available() returns > 0 there is data that can be read without blocking, and read() will read that and not block.

Comment: this seems to work.. :) I didn't understand people's problem with this method, this doesn't block like BufferedInputStream.. thank you very much, if anybody else can explain to me again why this shouldn't be done I will be happy to hear, and thanks again for the answers

Comment: @Amir.F Tge problem with using `available()` is that people think it will magically tell them when the incoming message is complete. It doesn't. The problem with this *answer* is that the first sentence is untrue.

Comment: I didn't want to know if the message is complete.. I wanted to know if I get any answer from server at all..because I have a device connected to IP Com, now the IP com is available, but if the device is disconnected then using read function will cause a block, can you demonstrate when using available could be a problem?

Comment: This doesn't help. The method "available" returns values which cannot be trusted. The java documentation warns about it. It may not be used for trying to avoid blocking read. Indeed, I have devices where "available" is always zero or always (!) non-zero .

Answer (score 3):

If you want to read responses asynchronously, I suggest starting a thread which read a BufferedReader.  This is much simpler to code and easier to control.

Comment: I thought that BufferedReader is the best practice for reading data without blocking. But for some devices,  "readLine" and even "ready" do block ("ready" shall never block): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27427213/bufferedreader-ready-blocking

Answer (score 1):

It's a tricky task not get blocking if you use standard java IO. Common answer is migration to NIO or netty. Netty is more preferable choice. However sometimes you don't have a choice so I suggest you to try my workaround:

```
public String readResponse(InputStream inStreamFromServer, int timeout) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStreamFromServer, Charsets.UTF_8));
    char[] buffer = new char[8092];
    boolean timeoutNotExceeded;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    while ((timeoutNotExceeded = (TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - startTime) < timeout))) {
        if (reader.ready()) {
            int charsRead = reader.read(buffer);
            if (charsRead == -1) {
                break;
            }
            result.append(buffer, 0, charsRead);
        } else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(timeout / 200);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                LOG.error("InterruptedException ex=", ex);
            }
        }
    }
    if (!timeoutNotExceeded) throw new SocketTimeoutException("Command timeout limit was exceeded: " + timeout);

    return result.toString();
}
```

This workaround isn't a silver bullet but it has some important feature:

- Doesn't use readline(). This method is dangerous for network communications because some servers don't return `LF/CR` symbols and your code will be stuck. When you read from a file it isn't critical you will reach end of the file anyway.
- Doesn't use `char symbol = (char) fr.read();`. This approach is slower than reading to char[]
- It has timeout functionality and you'll have possibility interrupt communication on slow connections

Comment: How was the sleeping time chosen? Could you switch `Thread.sleep()` for `Thread.yield()` instead?

Comment: according to documentation yield doesn't provide any guarantees. "A hint to the scheduler that the current thread is willing to yield its current use of a processor. The scheduler is free to ignore this hint."

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar recently using a CountDownLatch. There may be some better ways, but this is pretty easy, and seems to work reasonably well. You can adjust the wait tome of the CountDownLatch to suit your needs.

```
package com.whatever;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class TestRead {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestRead.class);
    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public void read() {
        URLReader urlReader = new URLReader();
        Thread listener = new Thread(urlReader);
        listener.setDaemon(true);
        listener.start();
        boolean success = false;
        try {
            success = latch.await(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error("error", e);
        }
        log.info("success: {}", success);
    }

    class URLReader implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            log.info("run...");
            try {
                URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
                URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
                in.close();
                latch.countDown();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("error", ex);
            }
            log.info("consumer is done");
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestRead testRead = new TestRead();
        testRead.read();
    }
}
```