# Timeout for check internet connection Android

Tags: java, android, connection, ping

I'm checking Internet connection state by pinging google. The problem is, when there is no connection and the waiting time is hyper-extended.

This is my code:

```
private boolean checkInternet() {
    String netAddress = null;
    try
    {
        netAddress = new NetTask().execute("www.google.com").get();
        return (!netAddress.equals(""));
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

public class NetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        InetAddress addr = null;
        try
        {
                addr = InetAddress.getByName(params[0]);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        } catch (IOException time)
        {
            time.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
        return addr.getHostAddress();
    }
}
```

I can not concatenate `isReachable(int timeout)` because it returns a `boolean` . How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to cancel a method if it doesn't complete in the allotted time.

The first answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164301/how-do-i-call-some-blocking-method-with-a-timeout-in-java) is probably the way I would go. Here it is slotted into your example.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Callable<Object> task = new Callable<Object>() {
    public Object call() {
        String netAddress = new NetTask().execute("www.google.com").get();
        return (!netAddress.equals(""));
    }
};
Future<Object> future = executor.submit(task);
try{
    //Give the task 5 seconds to complete
    //if not it raises a timeout exception
    Object result = future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //finished in time
    return result; 
}catch (TimeoutException ex){
    //Didn't finish in time
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly adding the corresponding exceptions. It was necessary to cast a boolean variable result. Thank you very much !