# How do I timeout a method after fixed time in java using concurrency executor future?

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency, cron

Using java concurrent executor, future cancel method not stopping the current task.

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164301/how-do-i-call-some-blocking-method-with-a-timeout-in-java) solution of timeout and stop processing of current task. But it doesn't stop the processing. 
I am trying this with cron job. Every 30 seconds my cron job gets executed and I am putting 10 seconds timeout. Debug comes in future cancel method, but it is not stopping current task.
Thank you.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "*/30 * * * * *")
    public boolean cronTest()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside cron - start ");
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
        System.out.println("Inside cron - end ");

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Callable<Object> task = new Callable<Object>() {
           public Object call() {
              int i=1;
              while(i<100)
              {
                  System.out.println("i: "+ i++);
                  try {
                      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                  }
                  catch(Exception e)
                  {
                  }
              }
              return null;
           }
        };
        Future<Object> future = executor.submit(task);
        try {
           Object result = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        } catch (Exception e) 
        } finally {
           future.cancel(true);
           return true;
        }
    }
```

The expected result is cron job runs every 30 seconds and after 10 seconds it should time out and wait for approximately 20 seconds for a cron job to start again. And should not continue the older loop because we have timeout on 10 seconds.

**Current result is:**

```
Inside cron - start 
2019/07/25 11:09:00
Inside cron - end 
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3
i: 4 ... upto i: 31
Inside cron - start 
2019/07/25 11:09:30
Inside cron - end 
i: 1
i: 32
i: 2
i: 3
i: 33
...
```

**Expected result is:**

```
Inside cron - start 
2019/07/25 11:09:00
Inside cron - end 
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3
i: 4 ... upto i: 10
Inside cron - start 
2019/07/25 11:09:30
Inside cron - end 
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3 ... upto i:10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is in this part of code:

```java
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

When you invoke `future.cancel(true);` your thread is being *interrupted* with `Thread.interrupt()`
Which means that when a thread is sleeping, it gets awoken and throws `InterruptedException` which is caught by the catch block and ignored. To fix this problem you have to handle this exception:

```java
catch(InterruptedException e) {
    break; //breaking from the loop
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

The second problem: `Thread.interrupt()` may be invoked while the thread is not sleeping. In this case `InterruptedException` is not thrown. Instead, the interrupted flag of the thread is raised. What you have to do is to check for this flag from time to time, and if it's raised, handle interruption. The basic code for it would look like:

```java
try {
     if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            break;
     }
     TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
}

       ...

// rest of the code
```

**UPDATE:**
Here's the full code of `Callable`:

```java
Callable<Object> task = new Callable<Object>() {
           public Object call() {
              int i=1;
              while(i<100)
              {
                  System.out.println("i: "+ i++);
                  try {
                      if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                          break; //breaking from the while loop
                      }
                      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                  } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                      break; //breaking from the while loop
                  } catch(Exception e)
                  {
                  }
              }
              return null;
           }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using 
```catch (TimeoutException ex) {
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
            future.cancel(true); 
        } 
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
            future.cancel(true); 
        }catch (Exception e) {
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
            future.cancel(true); 
        }``` 
and [refer 2nd comment]. But still isn't giving the expected result.

Comment: Other change that I made is:
`try {
   if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    future.cancel(true);
   }
   TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
            future.cancel(true); 
  }`

Comment: @Interstellar, use the code I provided in the answer. There's no need to catch `TimeoutException` and invoke `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` Just break out of the loop once `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` is true. Check the updated answer.

Comment: It is working with your solution. I appreciate it. Thanks a lot. So the related question is, here we are changing code inside call() to get expected result. If I am calling some external method then can I stop executing it without doing anything in call() method?

Comment: @Interstellar, if you mean interrupt the thread in an external method, then yes, you can. Your goal is to get to the end of the `call()` block, same as in a single-thread app.

Comment: So how can I achieve the end of `call()` block? The future.cancel(true) is not stopping that executing thread.

Comment: @Interstellar, same way you exit from any method. When there're no more instructions to perform, you exit from it. Same with `call()` .

Comment: I got your point, but my question is, without modifying `call()` method's while loop / any logic inside `call()`, with what code modification with `Future` object, can I achieve the result as I stated in question? The reason is, there are 3rd party methods and I don't have control over it. So without touching it, I want to stop it's execution after 10 seconds. Thank you.

Comment: @Interstellar, you can not do it with `Future` or `ExecutorService`. And actually, you do not need to do it. Imagine, what would happen if a thread gets stopped and leaves some resources unreleased?. Or simply owns a lock and never releases it. It's prone to mysterious bugs in your app. Any multithreaded code **must** handle interruption requests properly. If the 3rd party methods do not do that, you should probably consider it as a bug.