# Java: Halt method execution after a certain time

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, completable-future, java-threads

Say I have a method called doSomething, and I call the method like this:

```
int result = doSomething();
```

And suppose doSomething() takes 500ms to execute by default. However, I want to halt the execution of doSomething() if it goes over the limit of 300ms. Would it be possible to do that in Java?

I tried the following which didn't work:

```
    int res;
    long timestart = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long timeend = timestart + 30;
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() < timeend) {
        res = doSomething();
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164301/how-do-i-call-some-blocking-method-with-a-timeout-in-java

Comment: This isn't really practical to do unless `doSomething` checks the time limit itself, or responds to interrupts, or in some way cooperates with cancellation.