# How to stop a thread waiting in a blocking read operation in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, stream

I have a thread that executes the following code:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        int n = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        while ((n = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, n);
            out.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

where `in` is `System.in`. How can I stop such thread gracefully? Neither closing `System.in`, nor using `Thread.interrupt` appear to work.

Comment: what happens when you use interrupt?

Comment: @tulskiy: Thread continues running until Ctrl-D (EOF) is entered manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because reading System.in (InputStream) is a blocking operation.

Look here [Is it possible to read from a InputStream with a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-java-inputstream-with-a-timeout/808795#808795)

Comment: Thanks. Using NIO `FileChannel` extracted from `System.in` allows to stop the thread simply by closing `System.in`. Closing `System.in` results in `AsynchronousCloseException` which interrupts blocking `FileChannel.read`.

Answer (score 8):

You've stumbled upon a 9 year old [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4514257) no one is willing to fix. They say there are some workarounds in [this bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4329256). Most probably, you'll need to find some other way to set timeout (busy waiting seems unavoidable).

Comment: Interestingly when I stumbled into this it was even odder behavior. The interrupt worked but took 2.5 minutes! (ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the available() method (which is non-blocking) to check whether there is anything to read beforehand.

In pseudo-java:

```
//...
while(running)
{
    if(in.available() > 0)
    {
        n = in.read(buffer);
        //do stuff with the buffer
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
}
//when running set to false exit gracefully here...
```

Comment: Abritrary number, if you don't sleep you end up in a hot-loop spinning the CPU waiting for available bytes to read.  My assumption was this thread will spend most of its time waiting for input.

Comment: Using `available` almost does the trick. The problem is that in case of EOF `available` returns 0 and the thread continues execution. +1 to compensate for unfair -1 =)

Comment: I just thought about responsiveness... PeterMmms link says it all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-java-inputstream-with-a-timeout

Comment: Thank you! Your answer just saved my life!

Answer (score 2):

Is it safe to close in stream in other thread? 
It works for me. In this case, `in.read(...)` throws exception `SocketException`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give a user some time to enter data - maybe to allow overriding default values or interrupting some automated process -, then wait first and check available input after the pause:

```
System.out.println("Enter value+ENTER within 5 Seconds to override default value: ");
try{
  Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch {InterruptedException e){}

try{
  int bytes = System.in.available();
  if (bytes > 0) {
    System.out.println("Using user entered data ("+size+" bytes)");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Using default value"); 
  }
} catch(IOException e) { /*handle*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, and this is how I fixed it, using `in.ready()` :

```
public void run() {
    String line;
    // Some code

    while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
        try {
            if (in.ready()) {
                line = in.readLine();
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().wait(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // Do what we want when thread is interrupted
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but isn't it taking a lot of CPU by executing the loop all the time while there is nothing to read?

Comment: Actually that is why I made the thread wait for some time every iteration. But you are right, it is not as efficient as it could be. It depends now on what is software purpose.

Comment: Pretty sure this still hangs if there's no newline on the stream.  in.ready() returns true if there's a single byte, in.readLine() reads it, then keeps waiting (forever) for the newline.

Answer (score -3):

you can use a external flag for this

```
boolean flag = true;


public void run() { 
    try { 
        int n = 0; 
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; 
        while ((n = in.read(buffer)) != -1 && flag) { 
            out.write(buffer, 0, n); 
            out.flush(); 
        } 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        System.out.println(e); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: That won't interrupt an already-blocking call though, so it doesn't address the problem.