# How to properly interrupt a Java thread which is reading user input?

Tags: java, multithreading, bufferedreader

I have a time consuming task `compute()` that I want to manually abort on the user input "abort".

To this purpose I have a Runnable `InputAbort` using an infinite loop and a `BufferedReader` to scan for the user input. The problem arises when the user decides not to abort the long computation. In this case, the thread running `InputAbort` does not get interrupted properly preventing the JVM to finish (making the thread a daemon does work, but I think there must be a way to properly end the thread).

The problem does not occur when the user aborts the computation entering "abort". It also does not occur when I delete the line `s =  br.readLine();` in the Runnable and the user waits for the computation to finish.

**Starting the thread and the computation:**

```
ComputationObject co = new ComputationObject();

Runnable rInputAbort = new InputAbort(co);
Thread tInputAbort = new Thread(rInputAbort);

tInputAbort.start();
co.compute();
tInputAbort.interrupt();
```

**Runnable:**

```
public class InputAbort implements Runnable {
    private ComputationObject co;

    public RunnableInputAbort(ComputationObject co) {
        this.co = co;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String s = "";

            while ( ! Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() ) {
                s =  br.readLine();
                if ( s.equals("abort") ) {
                    co.abort();
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }

            br.close();
            isr.close();

        }  catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to timeout a thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread)

Comment: This question is *not* a simply asking how to timeout a thread; the thread reading the input must also be made to respond to an interrupt signal, even if it is blocked while reading.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question, but is it essential that the user stop the process through the command line? In the past I have used the presence of a file as a way for a user to communicate with a process. Not ideal I know but it would be a solution. The user issues "touch stop.stop" to create a file in the expected place, and the process then terminates because it has seen that the file is there.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770514/how-to-properly-interrupt-a-java-thread-which-is-reading-user-input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't interrupt a thread that is reading input. See [How to stop a thread waiting in a blocking read operation in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182491/how-to-stop-a-thread-waiting-in-a-blocking-read-operation-in-java).

If you just want to exit the JVM you could just do:

```
System.exit(0)
```

Comment: NP - probably should be closed as duplicate though.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for `ready()` on the `BufferedReader` solved the problem for me:

```
while ( ! Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() ) {
    if ( br.ready() ) {
        s =  br.readLine();
        if ( s.equals("abort") ) {
            cb.doAbort();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Further information here (even if my question really had nothing to do with timeouts):

[Is it possible to read from a InputStream with a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-inputstream-with-a-timeout/16313762#16313762)

Comment: Very very bad idea. The thread will spin on the loop waiting for input and chewing up CPU.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. Was that already a flaw in the original implementation or does the problem come from the check for ready()? Would it help to add sleep(1000) somewhere in the loop?

Comment: You could add a sleep at the end of the loop which will help. If you don't have a sleep it will continuously loop and your CPU usage will go to 100% on one core.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just to clarify: This does not have anything to do with ``br.ready()``, right?

Comment: Yes. Say there is no input, br.ready() returns false, you go to the top of the loop; the thread is not interrupted, you continue and check br.ready() again, etc., etc., several zillion times until someone types something or the  program finishes.