# Force stop a blocking read AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask in my application:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {
    private static Socket mySocket;
    private static InputStream myInputstream;
    private AsyncTask task;
    private boolean connected = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...            
        task = new UpdateTask().execute();
        ...
    }

    private class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
            if(!connected) {
                try {
                    mySocket = new Socket();
                    mySocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(MYIP, MYPORT));
                    myInputstream = mySocket.getInputStream();
                    connected = true;
                } catch(IOException e) { ... }
            }

            while(connected && !isCancelled()) {
                byte[] readbyte = new byte[1024];
                try {
                    myInputstream.read(readbyte);
                } catch (IOException e) { ... }
                ...
            }
            return null;
        }
        ...
    }
```

And I want to stop AsyncTask `task` when I close my application: (press back putton).
I tried the answer here [Android - Cancel AsyncTask Forcefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748964/android-cancel-asynctask-forcefully) to check `isCancelled()`

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            task.cancel(true);
            mySocket.close();
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

But it seems that application will block at `myInputstream.read(readbyte)` when `task.cancle(true)` is called.
Android will throw an "app is stop responding.." pop-up to me.
How can I force stop the blocking read?

Comment: Do you catch any exceptions in doInBackground? There should be an InterruptedException.

Comment: @Fildor it should be a `java.io.InterruptedIOException`, but only if the stream supports interruption.

Comment: You say " it seems that application will block at `myInputstream.read(readbyte)`". How sure are you that that is actually the case?

Comment: Because I use many `Log.d()` to print between the lines, it stopped at `read(readbyte)`

Comment: `mySocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(MYIP, MYPORT));`. You cannot do that in onCreate. The whole idea of using an AsyncTask is that you put such 'internet code' in doInBackground of an AsyncTask.

Comment: Get it, I modify the part into `doInBackground `

Comment: This is more like a java-related question, check this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182491/how-to-stop-a-thread-waiting-in-a-blocking-read-operation-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.io.InputStream` implements blocking I/O. It is expected that your application will block on

```
myInputstream.read(readbyte)
```

until the `read` operation will return `-1` which means that there no more data to read from stream (as it was closed or connection was terminated) or throw the exception.

The only way to unblock the thread waiting for data on stream is to close it. In your case you need to be able to close the `Socket` created in

```
mySocket = new Socket();
```

line.

```
mySocket.close();
```

should interrupt your reading. But stay aware that [`Socket.close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close%28%29) actually

> Closes this socket.
>
> Any thread currently blocked in an I/O operation upon this socket will throw a SocketException.

So you task tread will get unblocked but you have to handle the `SocketException` correctly in your task to terminate all operations (*maybe this is what you are missing*).

FYI calling the

```
task.cancel(true);
```

doesn't make much sense as this only sets the `cancelled` flag on task. It is responsibility of your code to check for the flag and with blocking I/O you have no possibility to do it.

Alternatively you should consider using non-blocking I/O.