# Set manually timeout for DataInputStream

Tags: java, network-programming

I am establishing standart TCP connection between two stations(A,B)
A is sending message, B recieving and sending response back, and then I close the connections.

- Stations B is "blackbox", I cant access change or do anything there.

Sometimes there is situation when B didnt send response back, and then I need to re-try the whole process again.

I want to set timeout on the reciveing time of Station A (which wait for B for an answer).
So basically when the waiting time is expired, i will dispatch a retry.

I didnt find  a way how to set a timeout for DataInputStream. (only for the whole socket connection - which I dont want)

some code:

```
 /**
 * Method receives the Server Response
 */
public byte[] receive(DataInputStream is) throws Exception
{
    logger.debug(TAG + " Client Recieving...");

    try
    {

        byte[] inputData = new byte[1024];
                     // here I want to set timeout for the "receiving mode"
        is.read(inputData);
        return inputData;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(TAG + " Couldnt receive data from modem: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a non-blocking `SocketChannel` instead of a `DataInputStream`.

Example:

```
private static final long TIMEOUT = 500;

/**
 * Method receives the Server Response
 */
public <C extends SelectableChannel & ReadableByteChannel>byte[]
receive(C chan) throws IOException
{
    logger.debug(TAG + " Client Recieving...");
    try
    {
        Selector sel = Selector.open();
        SelectionKey key = chan.register(sel, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        ByteBuffer inputData = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        long timeout = TIMEOUT;
        while (inputData.hasRemaining()) {
            if (timeout < 0L) {
                throw new IOException(String.format("Timed out, %d of %d bytes read", inputData.position(), inputData.limit()));
            }
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            sel.select(timeout);
            long endTime = System.nanoTime();
            timeout -= TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(endTime - startTime);
            if (sel.selectedKeys().contains(key)) {
                chan.read(inputData);
            }
            sel.selectedKeys().clear();
        }
        return inputData.array();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(TAG + " Couldnt receive data from modem: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First check out `socket.setSoTimeout(timeout)`

Second, see this discussion: [Is it possible to read from a InputStream with a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-java-inputstream-with-a-timeout)

read method is blocked. The only way to check whether stream contains data without blocking is using `available()` method. So you can try to call this method with certain delay and exit if nothing is available after n seconds. You can write your own input stream that wraps any other input stream implementing this logic. The reference above shows how to do this.