# Time limit for an input

Tags: java, eclipse

Suppose I have a code where it asks the user to give some input, something like this:

```
for (condition) {
System.out.println("Please give some input");
System.in.read();
} //lets say this loop repeats 3 times and i face a problem during second iteration
```

but I want to give the user a 60 second time limit, and then throw an exception (in this case, I think its `TimeOutException`). How do I do that?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-java-inputstream-with-a-timeout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.io.*;
public class test
{
    private String str = "";

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            if( str.equals("") )
            {
                System.out.println( "you input nothing. exit..." );
                System.exit( 0 );
            }
        }    
    };

    public void getInput() throws Exception
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule( task, 10*1000 );

        System.out.println( "Input a string within 10 seconds: " );
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
        str = in.readLine();

        timer.cancel();
        System.out.println( "you have entered: "+ str ); 
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try
        {
            (new test()).getInput();
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println( e );
        }
        System.out.println( "main exit..." );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other simpler way?Because I don't have timer and timertask classes in my java.util package

Comment: start thread, simply use while loop for your time and after interval use thread.destroy();

Comment: i have something to ask u..lets say i have written this - 
                 
Thread t = new Thread();            
t.start(); //i started a thread     
do {//my logic}while(condition);       
t.destroy();   //i destroyed the thread.but not sure why.     

Is my code skeleton correct? And what is the condition i have to put inside while()?     

Can u pls clear all of my doubts?

Comment: in your case you dont need to use while because you want to exit if user input something, so if user not inputs something then u have to wait for specified time so so your login is right just remove while loop

Comment: I guess i didn't tell u properly. I want to wait for the user to input some value. But i want to wait only for a few seconds. After that specified time i want to show an error and exit.Also now my problem is, the sysout and sysinread - both come inside a for loop. So is it not possible for me to continue with the next iteration?I have updated my code..

Comment: what is task statement?

Answer (score 1):

I use joda-time for this kind of stuff:

maven:

```
  <!--  Joda Time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

When prompting to input, set a LocalDateTime variable:

```
 LocalDateTime timeOut = new LocalDateTime().plusSeconds(15);
```

And loop until user either inputs or the timeout is reached:

```
 if (timeOut.isBefore(new LocalDateTime())) {
 //throw your exception if this case happens
 }
```

Comment: Is there any other simpler way?Because I am not using that maven in my project.

Comment: You can use joda-time without maven aswell :p

Answer (score -4):

How about something as simple as this:

```
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    long limit = 5000L;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Long l = reader.nextLong();
    if ((startTime + limit) < System.currentTimeMillis())
        System.out.println("Sorry, your answer is too late");
    else
        System.out.println("Your answer is on time");
```

This will not throw an exception, only inform the user about being too late with his answer. (related to another question that was referred to this post).

Comment: This will wait until you provide an input.