# How do you detect if there's not input from user (java)

Tags: java, input, compiler-errors, nullpointerexception, line

ok so I am working this project where you have to do something with inputs from user

let says if he enters

"12 3"

But he doesn't input the second input

And let's say if i call it with

```
String something = in.readLine();
```

if i were to call

```
String nextLine = in.readLine();
```

i get errors. how do i check if there's no second input?

public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{

```
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); //ctr + shift + o


    String eachLine = in.readLine(); //ex. "12    5"" or "AB     12"


    String nextLine = in.readLine();
```

if the user input

"3  2" <<

but does not enter the second one..i get nullpointerexception

Comment: Can you post your code fragment?

Comment: Use something like split and control the count …

Comment: If there is no more input in.readLine() will return null.

Comment: my goal is...i want to find out how many lines of inputs does the user input

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "he doesn't input the second input":

- If you mean that the user enters the EOF character (e.g. CTRL-D on Linux), then what happens is that the `readLine()` method will return a `null`, which your application can (and should) explicitly test for.
- If you mean that the user simply enters nothing, then nothing happens.  Your application will just sit there waiting for the user to enter the next line.  To deal with that, you need some kind of timeout mechanism ...

Comment: ok i mean he enters the first input and save and compile. when i tried to do String nextLine = in.readLine(); i get error.

Comment: @LeafC - I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) class for this purpose.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853989/time-limit-for-an-input)

Something like..

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
public void run(){
if( input is empty ){
System.out.println( "you input nothing. exit..." );
System.exit( 0 );
}
}
};
```

Schedule the `Timer`..

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule( task, timeoutTime);
```

//Read the input

```
String nextLine = in.readLine();
```

//Cancel the timer..

```
timer.cancel();
```