# How to set a time limit for user to enter input?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm making an application that simulates a simple game. It is necessary to limit the players, so they have 60 seconds to enter their answers. I have a problem if they don't type anything and the time limit expires, then it's necessary to close the Scanner (System.in) that I opened so that they could enter their answers, and give 0 points to one who did not respond in time. If anyone has a solution for me, please help me.

Comment: This should help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853989/time-limit-for-an-input

Comment: I've seen it, does not work for me. Input stream remain blocked so it cant be done another entry from the users that I need  when game continous. I tried with threads but cant interrupt a thread which performs input and it continues to run in the background, even i call Thread.interrupt()...

Comment: The detailed answer is mentioned in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853989/time-limit-for-an-input

Answer (score 1):

Try TimerTasks, check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html