# Scanner class and timer

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am making a game in which I am accepting input using the Scanner class. I have added the Timer and TimerTask class. When the question is displayed, it waits for the user to enter the answer. What I want is, if the user doesn't give an input, in say 10 seconds, the program should move to the next question and if the user answers, it should accept the input. The problem with my code is that it is not moving to the next question but is waiting for an input. 
Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please consider showing your code.

Comment: Did you try to check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853989/time-limit-for-an-input)

Comment: I'm not an expert, but what about an ansynchronous task, which runs a while true loop, and constantly checks the current time - input time. And an if statement that breaks the loop and returns to the main thread and runs a specific method when this time exceeds a limit.