# Time limited for user input

Tags: java

java newbie here, i am a little bit stuck about a case.

My program will generate a random question to user, and user only have time for let's say just 5 seconds to answer it.

```
boolean passedTimeLimit = false;
System.out.println("Question 1 : what is the product of 24566771 multiply 9121315?");
String ans1 = input.readLine(); //Timer here waiting for input

if (passedTimitLimit) {
   // 5 points
} else {
   // 10 points
}
```

What is the simplest approach to set the timer here?

I've  been googling around about it, but it seems that everyone using class timer for this, i personally think it's overkill, maybe.

(i repeat, i have googling around to find a simple solution for this case, not a solution using Timer or TimerTask, not BlockingQueue either)

Comment: Where is your input coming from? The terminal window?

Comment: yup, terminal window

Comment: There was also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853989/time-limit-for-an-input?rq=1

Comment: yes, i've read that one, that's why i asked is there any simpler approach, heck i just want it simple, can't i just use while? or something like that?

Comment: Someone closed your question for an answer so here you have a simple answer in a comment. Try it. 

look at my answer at the above link  of the previously related question

Comment: well you put it way simpler, going to test it now