# Close a Scanner after 10 Seconds and No Input

Tags: java

I have a scanner in my main method that waits for a response. Is there any way I can close the scanner after a period of time with no response? I believe I am able to do this with an additional thread but I do not know if there is a better way.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
String input;
Scanner playerInput;
playerInput = new Scanner(System.in);
input = playerInput.nextLine();
```

Comment: post your  code @user

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time limit for an input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853989/time-limit-for-an-input)