# Reset timer on user input

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a program that receives user input, if no input within 1 minutes, the program ends, otherwise the timer resets and waits for user input again.

I'm only able to do a timer until now and can't find a way to implement it with user input.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.io.*;
public class test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            int sec = 10;
            public void run() {
                if (sec > 0){
                    System.out.println(sec + "seconds");
                    sec--;
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Time's up");
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( task, 0,1000 );
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's not necessary to show how many seconds left in the program though.

Answer (score 0):

Heavily inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5854048/18277288), I've adopted the given solution to your problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Test {
  private static final int DURATION = 10;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("Failed to receive input.");
        //Maybe: System.exit(0);
      }
    };

    timer.schedule(task, DURATION * 1000);

    System.out.println("Provide input within " + DURATION + " seconds.");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input = s.nextLine();
    timer.cancel();
    System.out.println("Success! Your input was: \"" + input + "\".");
  }
}
```

Start the timer first, before asking the user for input to assure it is running. When java executes `s.nextLine`, it will wait for the user to insert something followed by a newline (Enter). While the program waits, the timer is running in the background. If an input is received in time, you can cancel the timer, else the `TimerTask` is executed, and you can either let the user know or exit the program (optional).

Side note: Following the Java naming convention, I've renamed the class ;)

Comment: Thanks for the input! However, after the user inserted an input, the timer should restart and wait for user input again instead of doing timer.cancel().

Comment: You could place the code in a loop or re-schedule the task. I'm happy to update the solution if you want to maybe give a little more context if that wouldn't do it by itself.