# How to Prevent Dos attack for BufferedReader readLine() method in Java?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, denial-of-service

I have situation where I am using BufferedReader `readLine()` to read data from a socket, but `readline()` reads data until it finds new line character/ return carriage in the Data.
And if my data does not contain new line character then it will keep on reading the data until it finds a new line and an intruder can inject DOS attack. 
And even socket can timeout.

I know one solution might be we need to restrict line size and read only some data, and append data to the buffer.

Is it optimal solution or i can do it in some other way?.

I can override BufferedReader and override readLine() method. Is it feasible solution?.

Comment: See also [Is it possible to read from a Java InputStream with a timeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-java-inputstream-with-a-timeout)

Comment: A very good answer by Subhas - [https://stackoverflow.com/a/17142341/748087](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17142341/748087)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most Robust way of reading a file or stream using Java (to prevent DoS attacks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084657/most-robust-way-of-reading-a-file-or-stream-using-java-to-prevent-dos-attacks)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Socket.setSoTimeout(int)`

Qutoing from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int))

> Enable/disable SO_TIMEOUT with the specified timeout, in milliseconds. With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a read() call on the InputStream associated with this Socket will block for only this amount of time.
>
> If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still valid. The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking operation to have effect. The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

Also note that from this line

> The option must be enabled prior to entering the blocking operation to have effect.

you must call `Socket.setSoTimeout(int)` before doing the `read` operation.