# JAVA IO : Issue with reading a stream using BufferedReader

Tags: java, json, httpclient, bufferedreader

am trying to read a JSON response using buffered reader as shown below. I'm using Apache Commons Http client. Response comes as a single line JSON and no of characters are around 1060000 and size is approximately 1 MB. Problem am facing is only part of stream is read by reader and other part is missing. How can i read the full JSON without losing any data.? Is this related to 'CharBufferSize'  of BufferedReader or no of characters in the stream ?

```
InputStream stream = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line);
}
```

Comment: getting any error ???

Comment: You don't need *both* a BufferedInputStream *and* a BufferedReader. I don't even see why you need the StringBuilder. Surely you can parse the response directly from the network?

Comment: Edited the code.Yah BufferedInputStream is not required. @HussainAkhtarWahid Not getting any errors. But at the end i'm getting only a part of the full String.

Answer (score 0):

try using a json parser.

```
    import org.codehaus.jackson.*;

    JsonFactory fac = new JsonFactory();
    JsonParser parser =  fac .createJsonParser(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to copy the complete stream into the `StringBuilder`, you should use the `InputStreamReader` and a `char`-array buffer.

```
InputStream stream = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();

InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

char[] buffer = new char[4096];
int read;
while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    builder.append(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i was able to solve using the **IOUtils** in Apache Commons library. Here is the code.

```
BoundedInputStream boundedInputStream= new BoundedInputStream(stream);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(boundedInputStream,"UTF-8"));

StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
StringBuilderWriter writer = new StringBuilderWriter(builder);

IOUtils.copy(reader, writer);
```

Although it is been a while, it may be helpful for someone.

Here is the **original source**, 
[Most Robust way of reading a file or stream using Java (To prevent DoS attacks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084657/most-robust-way-of-reading-a-file-or-stream-using-java-to-prevent-dos-attacks)