# Is there a way to have a time out when reading from a input stream Java?

Tags: java, tcp, timeout, inputstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to read from a Java InputStream with a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-java-inputstream-with-a-timeout)

I noticed that when I was trying to read in more information then was sent to my server, the web browser would freeze.  I saw that my socket froze, since the web browser was returning less information then it was trying to read.  Is there a way to set out a time out on  Currtly I’m using a input stream

```
public String ReadLine()
 {
    String out;
    out="";
     // read in one line
     try{
         request = new StringBuffer(1000);
        boolean f=true;
        while(true)
        {
            int c=in.read();
            if (c=='\r') 
                {
                // next should be a \n
  // Program freezed hear
                 c=in.read();
                if (f==true)
                    return "";
                 break;
                }
            f=false;
            out=out+(char)c;

            request.append((char)c);
                } // end while

     } catch(IOException ec)
        {
            System.out.println(ec.getMessage());    
        }

        System.out.println(request);


    return out; 
 }
```

Comment: could you please fix the formatting? Just select the program text and click the {} button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Socket.setSoTimeout()` or `HttpURLConnection.setReadTimeout()`.

Answer (score 1):

It was discussed here: [Is it possible to read from a InputStream with a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-java-inputstream-with-a-timeout)

As far as I can see, the solution is provided.

Comment: Hi,thank you.  I did Google the question and usually stack over flow will show up if it has a question with those keywords.

Answer (score -1):

you have a couple of choices but it isn't pretty. the 'normal' java socket io doesn't have timeouts nor do the streams

1. do your reading in a separate thread and queue up the input data
   with a timeout mechanism of your own
2. use  java nonblocking IO api

   http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/

Comment: Wrong. The 'normal' Java socket I/O has `Socket.setSoTimeout()` and `HttpURLConnection.setReadTimeout()`. Streams that aren't attached to sockets don't have any reason to timeout other than perhaps from the console.