# How to set the read timeout for InputStream.read?

Tags: java, inputstream, settimeout

If the server never send EOF, will InputStream.read hang?

How to set the read timeout?

Comment: *"If the server never send EOF.."* ..fix the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-java-inputstream-with-a-timeout

Answer (score 2):

How about setting a socket timeout. It sets the timeout on all the read operations on that socket