# How to unblock Inputstream read method when connected to a wifi without internet on Android?

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I'm working on a program on android which should update itself when there is a new version. I use the class `HttpUrlConnection` to connnect to the server, and then I get the `inputstream` of the connection. I put `inputstream.read(byte[] buffer)` in a loop in a thread surrounded by try & catch.

When I disconnected the wifi (not turn off), the IOException was thrown out. However, if I disconnect the router from the network, `inputstream.read(byte[] buffer)` was blocked without any exception thrown out. It remains blocked without timeout.

How to unblock the `read()` method to inform the client that he is disconnected form the network?

Any solution or hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-inputstream-with-a-timeout

Comment: No problemo. Glad to help.