# How to end inputstream.read in java

Tags: java

I am trying to read data from 5 devices connected serially. My Java code is running fine if the device is healthy, if not then `inputstream.read()` hangs the program and does not allow further execution.

I have tried using `inputstream.available()`, `BufferedInputStream`... but nothing works.

What I want to do is: if a device does not respond my code, it should end itself and let the control go to the main program where it will go to the next device. The socket remains open for one cycle of polling.

```
Socket es = new Socket("10.12.90.153",4001); 
OutputStream osnew= es.getOutputStream(); 
InputStream isnew = new BufferedInputStream(es.getInputStream());
```

This is done in the task program, then I pass `osnew` and `isnew` to each device at a gap of one second for further action. The `osnew` writes some data to which the device responds. Then I read from `isnew`...This where the program hangs.

Comment: can you write a loop like while(value!=null){value=read()} ? below that loop you could write your exit-routine

Comment: I think the answers of http://stackoverflow.com/q/804951/946328 can help you

Answer (score 0):

`InputStream` is designed to block when you try and read data and none is available.  You could call the `available()` method to see whether any data is available to read without blocking, but this only works one way - if `available()` returns non-zero you know you can read without blocking, but if it returns zero you won't *necessarily* be blocked.  It is perfectly valid for an input stream to *always* return zero from `available()`.

You may wish to look into the non-blocking I/O APIs of `java.nio` instead of using streams.

Comment: I tried using bufferinputstream.available as well as inputstream.available....Both donot work

Comment: if(isnew1.available()>0)
  {   // read response
              i = isnew1.read(ibufnew1, 0, 261);  // do stuff
             
  } This blocks the healthy devices too

Answer (score 0):

You could handle each device in a separate thread. That way your program will stay responsive even when the devices aren't. But be aware of the pitfalls of multithreaded programming.

More information about multi-threaded programming in Java can be found on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Multithreading may not be workable in my case as the Ethernet device connected to serial devices allows 2 connections at a time as well as Once I have data from all 5 devices I push it in database

Answer (score 0):

How are you reading from the device?  I'll assume you're using some form of FileInputStream to do it.  That class looks to be suitable for reading from a filesystem to me, but a device, which could block for a long period of time is likely to lock up the Java thread until the device does respond.  You need to make some kind of timed read request of the device, and I don't know of any Java class that does that.

Best suggestion I have is to write some JNI code that talks nicely and doesn't block when your devices stop responding.  This is what I did when I was talking to a USB device.  If I were coding this (for Linux) I would use select (which has a time period argument) to wait of an input from any of the devices.