# Is there a way to know if a timerTask has completed?

Tags: java, timer, timertask

My problem is: I have two blocks of code.. One block I execute only if the Timer reached 10seconds.. so I invoke the TimerTask with the piece of code.. The other block of code I execute only if I don't get into the TimerTask function.. (the run() function).. 
Is there a way to know if a TimerTask has completed its execution, like returning a Boolean variable, for example? I'm programming in Java.

I tried:

```
TimerTask emd = new EsperaMensagemDigitada(outgoing, incoming);
timer.schedule(emd, 10000);
if(emd.cancel() == true){
   messageOut = userInput.readLine();               
   outgoing.println(messageOut + "            [Sua vez]");
   System.out.println("Aguardando resposta...");
   outgoing.flush();    
}
```

but it seems that it will ALWAYS execute the code inside the if clausure.. so I dind't resolve my problem yet..

The other part of this problem is that I have this code:

```
messageOut = userInput.readLine();
```

I want, if the user doesn't enter any message for 10 seconds I print a default message, if he entered a message until 10 seconds, I print his message. The problem is I get stuck on userInput.readLine(), waiting for an entry..

Comment: One way: give the code running in the task property change support so that you can notify listeners when it changes state.

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to cancel the TimerTask using [`TimerTask.cancel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel%28%29) which returns `boolean` value that is **true** if and only if the cancel resulted in the scheduled task not running and **false** otherwise (meaning the task has already been fired and may be in progress or already done with the `run()` method)

Comment: This looks to be better than my suggestion in comment. 1+

Comment: strange, but when I tried to execute the code:
if(timer.cancel() == true){
...
}
I got the error: error: 'void' type not allowed here

Comment: @ChristianeOkamoto You don't cancel the `Timer` you cancel the `TimerTask`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rather use [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) with [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for this purpose. `FutureTask` has an [isDone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#isDone%28%29) method to check if it is completed. Since `TimerTask` implements `Runnable`, you can wrap your task quite easily in a `FutureTask`:

```
FutureTask<?> futureTask = new FutureTask<Void>(timerTask, null);
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.schedule(futureTask, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
if (futureTask.isDone()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I still don't get it.. :(
My problem is that I have this code: messageOut = userInput.readLine(); 
I want, if the user doesn't enter any message for 10 seconds I print a default message, if he entered a message until 10 seconds, I print his message. The problem is I get stuck on userInput.readLine(), waiting for an entry..

Comment: @ChristianeOkamoto  I misunderstood the question: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-inputstream-with-a-timeout) question then