# InputStream reader blocking thread

Tags: java, inputstream

I wrote this InputStream reader to listen to a Socket. This code is in a `while(!stop)` loop inside the `run` method of a thread. This reader blocks the thread, and does not print the message.

```
int read = 0;
byte[] buf = new byte[512];
int index = 0;
try {
    while (!stop && (read = in.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.println("read loop");
        buf[index++] = (byte) read;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Does your client/server ever stop writing? Does it flush or close the stream on its side.

Comment: The `InputStream` provided by a `Socket` is blocking. This expected behavior. Or you could send it 513 bytes and get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

The read indeed blocks the thread running if no data is available.

What you want is to read a byte with a timeout ?

Look for answer to this in [Is it possible to read from a InputStream with a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-inputstream-with-a-timeout)