# Reading from an InputStream without blocking

Tags: java, nio

I have a few `InputStream`s that I would like to read from in a non-blocking manner. Here is the example:

```
public Result getResult(InputStream ... inputStreams) {
    final Result result = new Result();

    for (InputStream stream : inputStreams) {
        // TODO: read input streams without blocking here
        // write output using result.log.add(...) when it gets to a \n (newline)
    }

    return result;        
}

public class Result {
    public final Collection<String> log = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();
}
```

So I could start a new thread for each `InputStream` via something like:

`new Thread(() -> { // TODO: read here }).start()`.

or even use an ExecutorService but I would prefer not to be starting threads myself and have this managed by the JDK. Is something like this possible?

(I have a process that prints the `Result.log` on request.)

Comment: @A4L - I do not wish to manage the threads myself, either by new threads or a pool...I wish for it to be done by the JDK if at all possible.

Comment: What kind of `InputStream`s are you working with? Files, network?

Comment: @axtavt - could be anything, but will mostly behave like network...sporadic stream, but does finish.

Comment: Why? Do you have a *specific requirement* to poll these streams? In a specific order? Regardless of the activity rate on each?

Comment: Not to do with requirement...I don't need an order, I guess what I am looking for is an "evented" IntputStream where all the threading and polling is taken care of for me by the JDK.

Comment: For some other use cases (reading all the available data from an `InputStream`), I found this question useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-inputstream-with-a-timeout

Answer (score 1):

You can partially do this with something like [`AsynchronousFileChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html).  This helps in that you don't have to wait for the file to read, once the file has been read the JDK will call the `complete` method of the provided [`CompletionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/CompletionHandler.html)(write your own to suit the needs listed).  The `complete` method runs asynchronously but the javadoc does advise you to ensure it runs as efficiently as possible to prevent blocking on other files (this could be an issue if you need multiple instances of `Result` to be generated at a time.

Hopefully this helps.