# Does the InputStream.read(byte[]) Blocking Mechanism Have a Timeout Value?

Tags: java, inputstream

According to the docs this method can return a '0' if the byte array is empty.  This shouldn't happen if the InputStream is empty and the read method is blocking unless it times out, right?  I can't seem to find anything in the docs about the method timing out.  I'm waiting 2 seconds before a place several bytes into the pipe during this 2 seconds I'm seeing several zeros being returned by the method in a while loop.

Comment: post your code pls

Comment: anyway, maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-inputstream-with-a-timeout