# How to limit download time itself in HttpURLConnection

Tags: java

There are many similar questions and

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("www.google.com").openConnection();

con.setReadTimeout(1000);
```

Is not a solution. I need to limit available time for download where if it takes more than 3 seconds to download the file it would throw an exception. 
**setReadTimeout** is respected only if data is not available for read for specified time which is totally different.

I'd like to prevent unpredictable thread block periods when reading from slow content providers.

Comment: No download is going on in the code shown in the question. There is nothing to limit.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-inputstream-with-a-timeout

Comment: @Andreas reaaally :-) ? OK, I am using  DataHandler accepting URL for SOAP but principle is the same as in : https://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/use-httpurlconnection-to-download-file-from-an-http-url

Comment: @Aubergine Ahh, but see, in *that* code the actual downloading is happening in the `while` loop, and you can easily add an `if` statement inside the loop to break out if elapsed time has exceeded a limit. Without code in your question that does an *actual* download, how can we suggest enhancement to the code to accomplish your desired goal?

Comment: @Andreas I will add more details ta.