# How can I read stdout/stderr contents from a Process which is still running?

Tags: java, inputstream, processbuilder

I have some problems using the [`Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) and [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) classes in Java. Here's my existing code, which works (this is code being executed in a JUnit test btw):

```java
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder()
        .command( commandLine )
        .directory( new File( directory ) )
        .redirectErrorStream( true );

Process process = processBuilder.start();

assertThat( process.exitValue() )
        .as( "Process exited with non-zero exit code. Stdout and stderr content:\n\n%s", readAllAsString( process.getInputStream() ) )
        .isZero();
```

The `readAllAsString()` method looks like this:

```java
private String readAllAsString( InputStream inputStream ) throws IOException {
    return CharStreams.toString( new InputStreamReader(
            inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8
    ) );
}
```

This works fine, but it doesn't handle all scenarios. What if the process doesn't exit normally, but sits and wait for input on its standard input? So, I'm trying to add something like this:

```java
if ( !process.waitFor( 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS ) ) {
    assertThat( false )
            .as( "Timed out waiting for process, aborting. Stdout and stderr content:\n\n%s", readAllAsString( process.getInputStream() ) )
            .isTrue();
}
```

...but this is where the problem starts. **The test sits and waits forever; it never reaches the end of the `InputStream`**. The `readAllAsString()` method probably reaches the end of the stream and then blocks, waiting on the process to write any more data to it. (Note: this is just my assumption, I haven't verified this in the debugger)

If I try to workaround this by adding a `destroy()` call like this:

```java
if ( !process.waitFor( 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS ) ) {
    process.destroy();

    assertThat( false )
            .as( "Timed out waiting for process, aborting. Stdout and stderr content:\n\n%s", readAllAsString( process.getInputStream() ) )
            .isTrue();
}
```

...I get an exception when trying to read the data from the stream:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:168)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:270)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:188)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:177)
    at java.base/java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:250)
    at com.google.common.io.CharStreams.copyReaderToBuilder(CharStreams.java:121)
    at com.google.common.io.CharStreams.toStringBuilder(CharStreams.java:179)
    at com.google.common.io.CharStreams.toString(CharStreams.java:165)
    at fi.hibox.test.scripts.CentreConsoleTest.readAllAsString(CentreConsoleTest.java:80)
    at fi.hibox.test.scripts.CentreConsoleTest.centre_console_can_call_getVersion_successfully(CentreConsoleTest.java:70)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

How can I workaround this? What's the proper way to read all the data from this `InputStream`, without blocking at the end of the available data? Or are there any other, better ways to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using [`CharStreams.toString()`](https://guava.dev/releases/32.1.3-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.html) for this is that it expects the stream to have reached EOF. In cases where the process is still running, this is not the case. If you rewrite the `readAllAsString()` method like this it works, with a few caveats:

- All input must be currently available. This method is non-blocking; it just reads the data from the `InputStream` which is currently available. Any output written by the process after the `readAllAsString()` method is called will not be included.
- This presumes that the buffer for the pipe doesn't get full. On my current Linux system the limit seems to be 1 MiB (`cat /proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size`).

#### Java 7+ implementation

```java
private String readAllAsString( InputStream inputStream ) throws IOException {
    if ( inputStream.available() == 0 ) {
        return "";
    }

    // Note: cannot use Guava's CharStreams.toString() in this case, since the stream
    // has not necessarily reached EOF yet (if we are called when the process is
    // still running)
    byte[] inputData = new byte[inputStream.available()];
    int bytesRead = inputStream.read( inputData, 0, inputStream.available() );
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap( inputData, 0, bytesRead );

    return StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode( byteBuffer ).toString();
}
```

Comment: There's no way for java, or anything else, to know whether some process is just taking its time in producing output, or if it's done writing stuff and will never write anything again from here on out / will only write more if you give it more (and you have no intention of doing so).

Comment: Agree. I think I was looking for a way to call `CharStreams.toString()` "with timeout", basically, according to my Firefox history of googling when I was trying to solve this. A colleague later helped out by pointing me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-inputstream-with-a-timeout, which helped me to update this helper method. But you are right, this might have been an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) from my part. Feel free to update this answer to make things clearer if you feel like it.

Comment: Your caveat and with this comment thread I think the answer can stand as a useful guide to anybody else looking for a solution. The notion of 'get me all the output' (without, perhaps, realizing 'all' is a tricky word there, when we're talking about process streams) is common enough :)

Comment: Instead of `ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap( inputData, 0, bytesRead ); return StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode( byteBuffer ).toString();` you can simply use `return new String(inputData, 0, bytesRead, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` This is not only shorter/simpler, the Java 9+ implementation will take shortcuts internally.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Holger. Our code base is unfortunately Java 8 yet, but we will (finally!) be able to use Java 9+ constructs in a few weeks. Feel free to edit my answer and list both versions (I think mine works fine on Java 7+, and your Java 9+ version), it would be a useful addition.

Comment: The [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D,int,int,java.nio.charset.Charset)) exists since Java 6, so you still can use it if your code base is Java 8 compatible. Only the efficiency advantage is higher when using Java 9 or newer (and the stack trace in your question suggests that you sometimes use newer versions at runtime)…